# JLabel center content in 3 rows

Tags: java, html, css, jpanel

I am trying to center the conent inside a JLabel and add the first three strings in three different rows. I tried to do it with CSS but the JLabel didn't format it like I wanted. What it currently looks like:

[image]


But I'd like it to look something like this:

================================
|| `Eleking02        vs.          Nils` ||
||
||   `.              7  -  3             .`
||
||`.              Gewonnen!            .`

```
pane.setText("<html><div style=\"color: green; text-align: left;\">" + this.getGewinner()
    + "</div><div style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: -17px;\">"
    + "Vs. </div><div style=\"margin-top: -20px; text-align: right; color: red;\">" + this.getVerlierer() 
    + "</div><br/>" + "<font>" + this.getSiegerPunkte() + " - " + this.getVerliererPunkte() + "</font><br/>"
    + "<font>Gewonnen!</font></html>");
```

Maybe I can achieve what I want with a gridLayout?

Comment: There are of course a number of ways to acheive this, but I'd recommend using GridBagLayout and multiple JLabels for your purposes

Comment: You can try https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/ and pass the HTML there

Comment: I would recommend using code.google.com/p/flying-saucer I made some great expierence with it.

Comment: Why do you ask about the gridlayout?? You could simply try it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty amazing that you can use HTML/CSS to style label fonts in Java. There might be multiple ways to solve this problem, but if you want to stick with using HTML/CSS, here is one way that seemed to work:

```
pane.setText("<html>"
                + "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">"
                    + "<span style=\"color: green; text-align: left;\">" + "Eleking02 " + "</span>"
                    + "<span style=\"text-align: center; margin-top: -17px;\">" + "Vs. </span> "
                    + "<span style=\"margin-top: -20px; text-align: right; color: red;\">" + " Nils" + "</span>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<br/>"                 
                + "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">" 
                    + "<font>" + "7" + " - " + "3" + "</font>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<br/>"
                + "<div style=\"text-align: center;\">" 
                    + "<font>Gewonnen!</font></html>" 
                + "</div>"
                + "</html>");
```

[image: Image of JLabel with formatting from CSS/HTML]

Div elements in HTML are block elements meaning that they automatically create a new line after each Div. You had multiple Divs and this would have prevented the text that you wanted from being all on one line. The span element does the same thing except it doesn't create the new line after the element. To center the text, I just placed what I wanted to center inside a Div and applied text-align: center. This seemed to do the trick.